# Deploying node/express app at DigitalOcean Droplet via CircleCI

Tags: node.js, continuous-integration, yaml, digital-ocean, circleci

I would like to deploy my MERN stack app in DigitalOcean Droplet via CircleCI as CI/CD tool. I read that it needs `ssh` into the Droplet and run commands for building and deploying the app, but I have tried a several ways to achieve it yet still ends up no luck.

Below is my `config.yml` for CircleCI

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  node: circleci/node@4.1.0
jobs:
  express_deploy:
    docker:
      - image: "cimg/node:current"
    steps:
      - run: node --version
      - add_ssh_keys:
          fingerprints:
            - "$ssh_key_prints"
      - run: ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no $username@$ip "cd $directory \ npm install \ node app.js"
workflows:
  init:
    jobs:
      - express_deploy
```

**error: `bash: line 0: cd: too many arguments`**

Some of the others attempts I have tried:

```
steps:
      - run: node --version
      - add_ssh_keys:
          fingerprints:
            - "$ssh_key_prints"
      - run: ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no $username@$ip "cd $directory"
      - run: npm install
      - run: node app.js"
```

**error: `module $directory/app.js not found`**

I wanna know if this approach is wrong or is there a way to fix it?

*notes: `$` are credential variables that I blurred here, but I tested them independently and they worked fine*

Comment: Do I need to config the target server somewhere else in the project config but not in the `yml` file?